# Android Camera2Video Preview Issue

Tags: android, xml, video-capture, android-camera2

I am using `Google's API` `Camera2Video` classes `Camera2VideoFragment` and `AutoFitTextureView` and I have a small problem. When I'm using the `preview` in a custom `FrameLayout`, it goes to the `left` corner.

I have found a way to sretch the preview for it to fill the whole `framelayout` but as expected, it looks way too stretched. Perfect solution would be if there could be some black edges on corners and the screen would be in the middle. Also I dont think making the inflator to inflate the layout from the middle would help because there could be cases where the screen is big enough for the preview to fit properly and that being positioned in the middle would just ruin it.

Link to `Google's Camera2Video API`: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

I created a simple `layout` to show what I get. (This is the only thing I have changed after downloading `Google's API`, and also removing the buttons that came with):

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context="com.example.android.camera2basic.CameraActivity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And a picture of what I'm seeing.

[image]

Comment: is this on device or emulator?. you should try it on device

Comment: @Raghunandan this picture was taken on an emulator just so i could screenshot it but it looks same way on device.

Comment: the sample works fine. also on what device and os versions are you testing

Comment: It works fine when you do it with the layout it gives you but If I put f.e a coordinatorlayout and the framelayout in it, this is what I get. Emulator -  Nexus 5X, Device - Motorola Moto C

Comment: Maybe it's because my phone's screen is smaller so the layout itself is smaller and it has to compress itself to fit with proper resolution.

Comment: Because I just tried to do it from the scratch and I got the same result.

Comment: Also I think that If I make the inflator to inflate the layout from the middle it will ruin thing for the screens where it would fit properly.

Comment: So, you set your frame to height of 250dp and expect its child to fill the screen?

Comment: @AlexCohn I do not expect it to fill it, rather I expect it to fit in the middle for example, not go in the corner. It can remain small.

Comment: Try to add `android:gravity="center"` for the **container** FrameLayout. Sometimes, this does not work reliably. Then, you can specify `android:layout_gravity="center"` for the **AutoFitTextureView**.

Comment: @AlexCohn but if someones screen is big enough for the preview to fit perfectly then it will still remain correct?

Comment: @AlexCohn anyways, I tried both of your suggested lines and none of them worked. If I understood correctly that is, I had to add them to the `FrameLayout` I had created?

Comment: `layout_gravity` goes on the **AutoFitTextureView** (id/texture) in fragment_camera2_video.xml or its equivalent, instead of [`android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera2_video.xml#L24). And you don't need the [RelativeLayout](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera2_video.xml#L16)

Comment: @AlexCohn It didn't wor when I had the RelativeLayout there, but once I removed it, it started working as requested. Even tho I'm not quite sure why that happened I am still really thankful for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a sample that wraps the **AutoFitTextureView** in an extra  [wrapper](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera2_video.xml#L16) of **RelativeLayout**. There it [defines](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/res/layout/fragment_camera2_video.xml#L24) the position of the texture view as

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

which caused the layout that you observed.

Your task does not need this wrapper. You can embed the **AutoFitTextureView** directly inside the **FrameLayout** of **CameraActivity**. Your **FrameLayout** should define

```
android:gravity="center"
```

to command the children to be centered.

Note that you can probably remove the wrapping **ConstrantLayout**, if its only child is the `id/container` **FrameLayout**.